# FOR look - Why does tokens=* never work for me?

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

For example, I'd like to parse through a single line like this with the `\` as my delimiter:

```
c:\some directory\another directory\filename.ext
```

So I set a variable:

```
set mydir=c:\some directory\another directory\filename.ext
```

This directory would change every time I run my script, so I may have no idea how many tokens are going to be in my string, but eventually I want to collect the entire sting, minus the last token.  The problem is, when I even try to test parsing with all tokens, I can never get it to return the results I expect.

When I use

```
For /F "delims=\ tokens=1-2" %a in ("%mydir%") do echo %a %b
```

I get

```
c: some directory
```

But when I use

```
For /F "delims=\ tokens=*" %a in ("%mydir%") do echo %a %b
```

I get

```
c:\some directory\another directory\filename.ext b%
```

Why is this happening?  It seems to ignore my delimiter when i use `tokens=*`.

I expect it to show

```
c: some directory
```

Comment: `*` means put everything into one token. What's wrong with normal methods `echo %~dp1`. See `call /?`.

Comment: Read the help for the FOR command.  Specifically the very last section.

Comment: **Never** use `for /F` and its `tokens`/`delims` to manipulate/modify/split paths! As the previous commands point out there are better ways, which handle all paths correctly, even special cases (like relative paths, root dir.s of drives, things like `.\sub\..\*`,...)! By the way: there are several typos in your code fragments -- please correct them (copy/paste them rather than retyping them)...

Comment: Typos fixed.  Thanks to all!  I had no idea of the existence of the shortcuts found in call /?.

Answer (score 2):

```
For %%a in ("%mydir%") do echo %%~dpa
```

should show you "the entire sting, minus the last token" as you claim to want (but I've doubled the `%`s which is required for `metavariables` in a batch file, not directly from the prompt)

The reason `tokens=*` isn't "working" for you (ie. doing what you expect it to do) is that the token `*` means `remainder of the string, past the last tokend number specified`. You haven't specified any tokens, so the "remainder" of the string is the entire string.

If you want `c some directory` then you are selecting the first and second tokens, so you'd use `tokens=1,2,*` which assigns the first token to `%%a`, the second to `%%b` and the remainder of the string to `%%c`. Note that the comma between the `2` and `*` is optional (and `1-2*` is also allowed).

In this case, `c:` would be assigned to `%%a`, `some directory` to `%%b` and the remainder of the line to `%%c`